# Have the function return the new array

Tags: arrays, function, return

Create a function that changes a given array to list each original element twice, retaining original order.  Have the function return the new array.  For example repeatTwice( [4,”Bird”, 42, true] ) should return [4,4, “Bird”, “Bird”, 42, 42, true, true].

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#reduce` method as in the demo below.

```js
const repeatTwice = arr => arr.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc, cur, cur],[]);

console.log( repeatTwice( [4,"Bird", 42, true] ) );
```

You can also use the `Array#flatMap` method as in the following demo:

```js
const repeatTwice = arr => arr.flatMap(element => [element,element]);

console.log( repeatTwice( [4,"Bird", 42, true] ) );
```